# Implement DefaultValueAccessor won't trigger "registerOnChange"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement this directive (https://plnkr.co/edit/yftpJ4A1HwrKkpfcSIT7?p=preview):

```
export class PrevValDirective {
  constructor(private valueAccessor: DefaultValueAccessor, private model: NgModel) {
    valueAccessor.registerOnChange = (fn: (val: any) => void) => {
      valueAccessor.onChange = (val) => {
        if(val === 'false') {
          return fn(model.value);
        }
        return fn(val);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

but by implementing DefaultValueAccessor / ControlValueAccessor (https://plnkr.co/edit/Vu9OJBmqhw8W5Rt9AIOJ?p=preview):

```
export class PrevValDirective implements DefaultValueAccessor {
  constructor(private model: NgModel){
  }

    registerOnChange(fn: (val: any) => void) {
        this.onChange = (val) => {
        if(val === 'false') {
          model.control.setValue(model.value);
          return;
        }
        return fn(val);
      };
    }
}
```

For some reason - `registerOnChange` won't trigger.

I would also like to change `onChange` to a regular (not annonymous) function but can't figure out how (I need the `fn` var).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `ControlValueAccessor` instead of extending an `DefaultValueAccessor`. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9146#issuecomment-241191899

To implement `ControlValueAccessor` you should provide `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` token for this directive. The simplest solution could look like this:

```
import { 
  Input, forwardRef, Renderer2, 
  Injector, ElementRef, Directive
} from '@angular/core'

import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

export const PREV_VAL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => PrevValDirective),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][prevVal]',
  host: {
    '(input)': 'handleInput($event.target.value)',
    '(blur)': 'onTouched()',
  },
  providers: [PREV_VAL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class PrevValDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() prevVal: string;

  onChange = (_: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(
    private _renderer: Renderer2, 
    private _elementRef: ElementRef, 
    private _inj: Injector) {
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }

  handleInput(value: any): void {
    if (value === this.prevVal) {
      let model = this._inj.get(NgControl);  // get NgModel
      model.control.setValue(model.value);   // set previous value
      return;
    }
    this.onChange(value);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't inject `NgControl`(`NgModel`) in class that implementes `ControlValueAccessor`. It will rise error

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NgControl

Luckily you can leverage `Injector` to get it as i did at this line

```
let model = this._inj.get(NgControl);
```

I also pass `prevValue` through `@Input`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val" prevVal="false">
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vRpUweN0lfCF0MKPff0b?p=preview)**

Comment: if I'm defining "input" event then why do I need to implement "ControlValueAccessor"? I mean, i thought that if I'm implementing  "ControlValueAccessor" I can use the onchange event - so that every change in the input will get there (without defining "input" or "keypress" events). please take a look at this plunker - I think that "triggered" should be shown after every input change - but it doesn't work:
https://plnkr.co/edit/HnQ0UH9NUQpWUc7iW318?p=preview

I'll be happy if you could make this one work without adding events

Comment: You need to implement ControlValueAccessor if you want to have component which supports validation and is compatible with both ngModel forms and Reactive Forms. And you should implement it if you want `registerOnChange` will be triggered. That's your question

Comment: `I think that "triggered" should be shown after every input change` it wont work because then your custom value accessor is used instead of DefaultValueAccessor that has `input` event handler whereas your directive doesn't

Comment: So this one (without customvalueaccessor) should have worked ? https://plnkr.co/edit/lrraBdzgzIcymPsAwR77?p=preview

Comment: No this shouldn't. This should work https://plnkr.co/edit/9I4zqLM28fY4RtgQ0qVd?p=preview

Comment: `registerOnChange` is raised on ControlValueAccessor. But your last example is just common directive

Comment: So from what I understand - If you want to implement onchange for  DefaultValueAccessor/ControlValueAccessor you have to add an hostlistener in order to trigger a change.
Why in the first solution (https://plnkr.co/edit/yftpJ4A1HwrKkpfcSIT7?p=preview) you could avoid using any hostlistener binding and trigger onChange event?

Comment: In the first solution we are getting existing DefaultValueAccessor that  triggers onChange internally https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.x/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L88 Dependency injection system helps us to get current instance of DefaultValueAccessor that is applied to this element

Comment: so by implementing DefaultValueAccessor the developer should trigger onChange whenever or whereever he decides but if i'm getting it out of the box (by using dependency injection) onChange is triggered in situations where angular2 core previously defined?

Comment: Yes if we use DefaultValueAccessor through DI we rely on existing implementation of ControlValueAccessor(DefaultValueAccessor) that is a built in directive.

Comment: Thanks man ! that's finally clear to me now. just one last question: the first solution doesn't supports validation and it won't throw error when submitting a form ? whereas the one that implements controlvalueaccessor supports form validation ? It would trigger an validation error on the component ?

Comment: Both solutions should support validation. 1) https://plnkr.co/edit/XLmVpU9b07DzYozHmdCM?p=preview 2) https://plnkr.co/edit/Tnv9gZUekZW4KHm7r7Ek?p=preview (notice `required` attribute) The first solution supports it because it uses DefaultValueAccessor. Second because it uses out custom implementation. We usually implement ControlValueAccessor for complex controls like DatePicker or our control with our own logic that we want to expose in component

Comment: can you please assist me in one more thing ? why is the input text gets updated if I'm updating the model similar to the example you wrote ?
https://plnkr.co/edit/k74OkLVgpwLJj444Jmsu?p=preview

Comment: You set previous value for `custom-input` control https://plnkr.co/edit/CahkJj1XCS8XvWP9KuoN?p=preview (observe `{{value}` in parent component) but `input` within CustomInputComponent template is updated because you don't reset it.

Comment: what I expect is that {{value}} value would always be inside the textbox. means that I can't write letters inside the textbox (they won't be shown). Currently I can write anything inside the textbox

Comment: 10x.. I see you've added : `target.value = model.value;` 
why do we need this line if we're doing: `this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);` on `writeValue` method ?

Comment: `this._elementRef.nativeElement` is `custom-input` element. And this line `this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);` hasn't any effect. You want to update inner input. I've just shown you how you can do it. You can also `[value]` or `ngModel` for inner `<input`

Comment: sorry to bother u but last question: i've tried to do this with ngModel but the text value inside the input is updated: https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZVK1fcSeWjkrQkdjpZm?p=preview

Comment: can you suggest why the textbox is updated even when ngModel is binded to innerValue ?